# Sum of list group by a field in c#

Tags: c#, .net

As a beginner in c# I am trying to figure out how to group and sum a data list inside a class.

`m_Invoice.InvoiceRow` includes "productId" and "price" fields. What I want to do is find total prices of each productIds

```
private void SendData(Invoice m_Invoice)
{
    try
    {
        int MCounter = 1;
        double MTotal = 0;

        foreach (var item in m_Invoice.InvoiceRow)
        {

            //**I need sth like: {{productId: 15, totalPrice: 128}, {productId: 19, totalPrice: 90 }}
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the invoice and invoice row classes?
And some sample input data (a sample invoice).

Comment: `m_Invoice.InvoiceRow.GroupBy(x => x.productId).Select(g => new { productId = g.Key, total = g.Sum(x => x.price) });`

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing with the result. Do you want a C# object of some kind? json? string? Console.WriteLine()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following query .  `m_Invoice.InvoiceRow` **Group by** `productId`

```
var mTotals = m_Invoice.InvoiceRow
          .GroupBy(a => a.productId)
          .Select(a => new { productId = a.Key, totalPrice = a.Sum(c => c.Price) });

foreach (var item in mTotals)
{
   Console.WriteLine("id : " + item.productId + " total : " + item.totalPrice) 
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but giving beginners a blob of code, especially one using LINQ, without any explanation at all is often detrimental to their understanding.

Comment: I do not know, maybe someone did not really understand the code of the phrase linq and considered it incorrect.

Comment: I used it as: var mTotals = m_Invoice.InvoiceRow
          .GroupBy(a => a.productId)
          .Select(a => new { productId = a.Key, totalPrice = a.Sum(c => c.Price) })

Comment: For final action I will call another method with those parameters: onInvoiceCommand(productId, totalPrice, m_Invoice.InvoiceRow) ...So I think with another loop in m_Invoice.InvoiceRow how can I get "productId" and "totalPrice" values from mTotals ?

Comment: well now I realized that in the beginning I can write each data and get there :) thank you

Comment: I edited the answer, see how to use it